# Cider's nREPL is messing up my Set literals

Tags: clojure, cider

When I try to type in a Clojure Set literal in the nREPL something is adding a space between the '#' and the '{' such that nREPL stacktraces when hit return at the end of the line.

```
; CIDER 0.8.2 (Java 1.7.0_71, Clojure 1.6.0, nREPL 0.2.6)
user> ;; If I type '#{' to try and start a Set literal something jacks in a space
user> ;; between the # and the { such that my form becomes invalid.
user> ;; How do I stop this bad behavior?
user> # {"one" "two"}
RuntimeException Reader tag must be a symbol  clojure.lang.LispReader$CtorReader.invoke (LispReader.java:1162)
user> ;; What I wanted was...
user> #{"one" "two"}
#{"two" "one"}
user>
```

What's causing that and how do I stop it?

I don't know if my .emacs.d/init.el matters, but its pretty lean regarding cider configuration...

```
; 2015-03-30 more Clojure support
(add-hook 'clojure-mode-hook 'paredit-mode)
(add-hook 'cider-repl-mode-hook #'paredit-mode)
(add-hook 'cider-repl-mode-hook #'rainbow-delimiters-mode)
```

I'm new to this Clojure thing, any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: try upgrading your clojure-mode, latest clojure-mode should have fix for that behaviour https://github.com/clojure-emacs/clojure-mode/blob/master/clojure-mode.el#L189-L207

Comment: @mavbozo that did the trick...I was 3.0.something and upgrading to 4.0.1 fixed the issue.  Thanks.

Comment: Btw, CIDER doesn't have an nREPL - it has a REPL. :-)

Answer (score 1):

@mavbozo solved it.  This issue is fixed in clojure-mode-4.0.1.  Nothing to see here.  Carry on.